# Did I translate "puissance mandataire" correctly?

Tags: traduction

I stumbled a bit on the phrase "puissance mandataire' while reading an [article from Le Monde](http://www.lemonde.fr/proche-orient/article/2017/11/18/liban-l-ex-premier-ministre-saad-hariri-recu-a-l-elysee-par-emmanuel-macron_5216992_3218.html) about the former Lebanese prime minister.

> Ancienne **puissance mandataire** du Liban, la France a joué les médiateurs et le président français a invité à Paris M. Hariri et sa famille afin de tenter de sortir de l’impasse née d’une démission apparemment imposée par les autorités saoudiennes.
>
> Former proxy power of Lebanon, France played the mediators and the French president invited Mr. Hariri and his family to Paris to try to break the impasse from a resignation apparently imposed by Saudi authorities.

I understand that France acquired a mandate over Lebanon after WWI. But how would you translate the phrase "ancienne puissance mandataire du Liban"? I'm having difficulty finding a suitable adjective. "Former mandatory power of Lebanon" makes no sense. But "Former proxy power of Lebanon" doesn't sound quite right.

A liberal translation is also possible, e.g. "Formerly having mandatory power over Lebanon, France has played the mediators..." But I'm much more interested in a simple and direct translation.

Comment: *Puissance mandataire* indeed means France had a [mandate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/League_of_Nations_mandate) on Lebanon. It didn't "acquire" it but was granted it by the League of Nations. How to translate *mandataire* to English should be asked to the [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) site but the wikipedia site states: "The mandates were fundamentally different from the protectorates in that the **Mandatory power** undertook obligations to the inhabitants of the territory and to the League of Nations."

Comment: proxy power covers exactly the meaning.

Comment: @baptistemm Done.

Answer (score 1):

*Puissance mandataire* indeed means France had a [mandate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/League_of_Nations_mandate) on Lebanon.

France didn't "acquire" it but was granted it by the League of Nations. How to translate *mandataire* to English should be asked to the [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) site but the [wikipedia site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/League_of_Nations_mandate) states:

> The mandates were fundamentally different from the protectorates in that the Mandatory power undertook obligations to the inhabitants of the territory and to the League of Nations.